# What does the phrase mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

1.2 Base board

- The base boards provides the following capabilities to the network module. The base board will be developed by AAA

  1) Feed all required DC power

  2) All signal input/output which defined in interface spec in the last page.

  ***3) Test pins for relevant signal input/output for the network module.***

I just want to know the meaning of the last sentence(Test pins for relevant signal input/output for the network module). Does this sentence mean that You should test the pins of network module in order to check whether signal input/output works well? Is that right?

Comment: No, it means that the board will provide "test pins" for the network module.

Comment: It's very poorly written.  (Or else inaccurately quoted.)

Comment: I think that maybe you got caught up on the way it sounds when saying "Test Pins" at the beginning of #3. Test Pins is a noun. This is similar to saying "Notebooks for homework at the front of the class," which sounds weird but still makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask this on a more technical Stackexchange site.  However, because of that word "capabilities" before the bulleted list, I think that here, *test* is a verb, and the bad writer is talking about the base board having the capability of testing the pins etc.  Which I guess means: that the base board should be set up in a way that allows for easy testing of the pins.  Or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

"Test pins" are convenient connections to specific parts of a circuit. They are not used in the normal operation of the device, and are used primarily for debugging or maintenance.

For example, imagine a simple, self-contained opamp-based amplifier, say built around a 741. There is no functional reason to bring the voltage supply lines out to external pins. However, if you're trying to debug it or function-check it, you might want to check that it's receiving power. Spare pins that connect to that voltage would be called "test pins."

This is describing a more elaborate system with more elaborate connections, but the principle is the same.